# NodeJS: Using in memory cache for performance and storage for persistance

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know if my following approach makes sense or if there are flaws that I missed:

The problem: SQL Queries are slow. In memory cache is not persistant.

My idea is to write my nodejs process in the following matter:

1. initialization
2. fetch current state from sql db and hold in variables
3. run all request queries on variables
4. update and alter variables, then update sql
5. respond only once sql was updated succesfully

With this approach I would completely eliminate SQL from running complex queries over multiple tables and can easily check stuff efficiently using id's as object keys.

Since NodeJS is single threaded I even have efficient "transaction" functionality as updating in memory variables will happen atomically.

Allthough this approach wont allow for horizontal scaling I feel like it would suffice for most of my projects.

Is there some fundamental flaw that I missed?

Comment: Some questions to ask yourself: Is it ok that some data gets lost? (ie. dropped frames in a recording). Is it ok to serve stale data for a limited amount of time? How much can you afford to mess with your architecture for the sake of performance? (if SQL is slow why not buy a faster server? or one with more cache memory)

Comment: What do you mean by "*In memory cache is not persistant.*"?

Comment: @Bergi If server crashes the data would be gone. By storing to sql and fetching after initialization my application would survive server crashes

Comment: The fundamental flaw: you basically said that you want to implement your own database engine in node.js. What could possibly be wrong with that?

Comment: @ThatBrianDude That's why it's called "in-memory *cache*", not "in-memory persistent storage". A cache already does exactly what you described you want, so why re-implement it?

Comment: @Halcyon What exactly do you mean with dropped fraes in a recording? I actually intended to do transactional stuff like user balances with this approach as well. Also, why would data be stale? The in memory cache would be my single source of truth, the sql would solely be to survive server crashes

Comment: @Bergi I was aware of that, hence my question...

Comment: @Bergi I wouldnt be writing a database engine. The data I am working with will be easily accesed via id's as object keys (Literally just 2 or 3 collections). SQL would be used only for server crashes

Comment: @ThatBrianDude you are looking for a way to improve performance but the way you suggest taxes flexibility heavily. This is not a tradeoff you make lightheartedly. Common ways of improving performance may include lossy storage and stale retrieval in such that they don't impact architecture too much. It's also good to keep in mind that databases are really good at what they do, they also perform really well for most generic purposes.

Comment: @ThatBrianDude It's still a database engine ("*run all request queries*", "*update and alter variables*") even when it's a no-sql database.

Comment: @Halcyon In what way does it tax flexibility? I dont seem to follow. Maybe you could elaborate on that point in an anwser

Comment: @ThatBrianDude well, you're basically implementing your own database on top of a database. You're not just caching data you're also processing mutations. At this point you have to wonder if you can't simply do away with your own implementation, use SQL directly and tune your database so it's optimized for your use-case. ie. why use a horse and carriage if cars are available? Maybe you don't need a car, maybe need a van or a sportscar, but we have those.

Comment: @Halcyon I get what youre saying. I feel like I need the cars ability to lock the doors but the horses ability to just start running without me putting my keys in first. This probably comes down to the fact that I want the sql to reside on a cheap vps but still be able to handle a large amount of data. I think I am getting closer to a conclusion...

Answer (score 0):

Things I would think of:

1. Your memory limit: How much data are you planning to hold in those variables? Can this data grow larger over time? If so, how do manage your available memory?
2. If you do complex "queries" you won't have the SQL benefit of indices (B-Trees). So your queries have to be simple lookups. For more complex queries you could think about temp/in-memory tables for your data. In SQLite you could use: `rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);` (https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).
3. I would make use of nodes child_process feature to keep your new mechanism away from your main thread (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Comment: 1. Memory limit wont be a problem. My current project would be a gamematching server so the data would be users and active games (vertical scaling is always an option). 2. As mentioned before I probably wont need any complex queries, just simple lookups. 3. What improvement would that bring with it?

Comment: Regarding the 3rd point. It would grant you more flexibility when your application grows over time (e. g. more users join your service). Also, what happens when you later want to implement features which require more complex data lookups? If you chose to use a second thread for your data fetch ops the response time would grow for some of your users but your application won't grind to a halt for all connected users.

Comment: I take it the child process would be accessing data from the main process? I understand. I will look into this